# Best way to get length of UTF-8 string in bytes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8

I want to get a cString from NSString.
So we used c​String​Using​Encoding:​ method.
However, the return value of the c​String​Using​Encoding:​ method is not guaranteed.
(Apple's doc: The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the receiver is freed.)
So Apple recommends the get​CString:​max​Length:​encoding: method.
I want to pass the exact length to maxLength.

Example 1)

```
NSString *tmp = @"中日韓" // cString 9bytes
char *buffer = new tmp[9 + 1];
[tmp getCString:buffer maxLength:9+1 encoding:NSUTF8String​Encoding];
```

Example 2)

```
NSString *tmp = @"中日韓123" // cString 12bytes
char *buffer = new tmp[12 + 1];
[tmp getCString:buffer maxLength:12+1 encoding:NSUTF8String​Encoding];
```

Is there a way to know the lengths of 9 and 12 in the example above?

Comment: Your code isn't valid and won't compile. Do you mean `NSString *tmp = @"your string";` or do you mean `char *tmp = "your string";` ?

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, my mistake. I edited it.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? You only have Objective-C code.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Add one because this doesn't include the NULL
NSUInteger maxLength = [string maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] + 1;
```

Comment: lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: is more precise -- it will get the actual length for the string (you still need to add 1 for NULL, of course).  maximumLength returns quickly but will be way over the necessary length for NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cStringUsingEncoding` to get the length. If you need the resulting `char *` to live longer than `tmp`, then simply copy the C-string:

```
NSString *tmp = @"中日韓" // cString 9bytes
const char *cStr = [tmp cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
size_t len = strlen(cStr);
char *buffer = new tmp[len + 1];
strcpy(buffer, cStr);
```